# GraphAPI V1 Delta Import issue

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Hello getting a current error when calling graph API from MIM using ECMA and trying to do delta imports

Delta calls give me this error out of graph

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "API version mismatch: request version 25 with deltaLink version 27",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "478063b8-b750-4448-bc11-36c5b87459da",
            "date": "2017-11-14T15:50:20"
        }
    }
}
```

The call being made is

```
https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/groups/delta/?$deltatoken=qqUEEKUqLwDi6qq-bg-nTaJxe-ckqs0PAEZwJypt1zejetmDvBtjX9o15GLqdVULRIbqv-el6F6tFjliwPwnDDnAeRMlgnPk8Wza8rt4Y16Emoqdq6jqoMOUOjYwFDyEyzWzuzYCuwZFCn1iuU5jUo33S7jaR-Mnn6fvthfoOJHumBxm4SMfNT0DjYKxCEb-x0Ts_NdqcswG26EG8HwuKtQVcg345m8eaFOm-mgU7lmSezVs1v-9Gw8z2rgNvyGXdxYdOeTqFl25gXQdakqdkDW-MT3kxwwEz_u4dyRjGYYm9r-ZdEzapfrg1gX9Trt3V2_UNU7C4TxzZ6IlmsU-seDmD6D-lmt0c-i7ICjGOzqrZ1HrBtxoVH8g4yL_IdIoOGXIJfkvcAFAhk9EPR7g6oCP5Ne4r2XdGQ6qUHyzq-xCIwFIocDnAY7Xc96N9phLnWO_TcLFsLJksTu2bxFix_pCOC3ZKiKJBG2lSlyhRE00Yj9XpX1paQ4e1nkKaNEZxKQHoJnWsTqOuqY1X59yldVOXboMpPFaPS5p1PJIPEZw2uSYGCp7d4g3JOLLAoftteu4nsCcr7cxESwG1br8ztHVFJjQyDVNUVq2-iSad0CG7RMJ2Z-CCntT34MgJ1-tL9wfHIOxn0YiyDB_jpi3MEVwI5Sgkwqq6tKx0Goa-fpU7cxIKpXmbHXttXo2OexF4aRe1i3EJv9DFBrMeCNqh0ykJFlDh-7fkyU3DgawKhGxQ9wPJMlCPzCbEbB8P-kpZlDfCxEYciRjLrl5lP2eXPPkNGzbfLM9PllwX-UnEJNlnzAxSpurL0_4HZ3hOup3bS-1EnZLnmv3BEKIOZWlhUG-sbnUJBefO2xzjkt5Mfb454SvDORTkMmGfJ3i7WHh1Fp8cK3ZOEM3dnjKle-2u8n7FDoyyAQ9FTXQitrIxvKb9iC1TaBxN7EgWw23a0-pQ531C7htZJ2V3zyeQ8uUM6MMKUaSA5pZRJjYl93S_EqFim4hqEH8C1sT_9bj1Zsh3SLWlhvWx-Yg9GSltfK17b46zLAcmwSYynCp8deXS8pBDMQB4vJkefG8Ozoc-XxVi5a7ULDiql20F4J4snBfv-C2Lh4rnJnE3t3JQXEocwVWSUAWELUvak2RyrQu_NDmTjF_5Pg1jX46F-f_q5H-2bteSLlpiOHoY893zuUuamYIhvsz7k1bvp47LK6rgxIRVhDBAqBYAY9CpDjmnQB8m7jpncACr2I5VqRoOzJqvLzw04lI4xQGsfFiul0-x9Xl0N8jb09Iil7X28LbUc1Y8cu2aiyEgKNwu4SwqVWhxzIx9dsw46LJIu_wB5a4T165UdrDj4waKDfn5-lWmqsfxs94MHX0uHTwk-xGNvTpMyxnmNHwHDXyiYfOiWt3x7NOH14SrCHsJuQjxhNQzKs0ta0sRWid3JOVQ2iocVTca29V8agdJsYnsBGiukCDlATd0tPdtdt18gCRRvmeXwLKfq3BFItfzFljRLjnYAjaaMczGzbUBFlxAzP1SBbPBfL--1xw7RcTcm6TSnB10zFe5IGAG74ZFwULkHtz7sFHgEOqVgKiTpRRaaWkCKNvne2i8zaZXvZKUL34PFXEmbnDI0OQmnVXZjMBrLjW3yse0yWbfVdOUCtECNxuGtbQLnNkSHqhwFgUdO5MzQFSodjTaWuYZhzjIKeIqBr0v3mS0Q-ClKFbb6MpC9bHwi6_bxZZwXJ5ueuewRcEJLerdMRZWGeqQ3YK3-FnR0v-3Z182sHixDUSsN3x6487PqY6xqV10EWbytwPuaP0qBgEkJ0RUvGhmemzByQh6aYaWNLciAZo705_bG_8v-f_ZB5uuBh6zeifuRvlyVlYr9h7aJrKlm8vT8BGW41NBjdW_uB-1wUsips-T89uqKjFUBUVIZrJfsx4eaKcOjxdbcerjbv7DLbvF1aQW_VUlTRU72GOaR4ZSIRbS0--I0UJTiFuzLSM7BlBEyj1hCO5KwE5GTusSiND1aHWYtoMIO6Sl2p69Oc9MwLt307vHVMUeYEWqshyaJu0NuzIxNAofUvzEtu37XEjM2dJkgcW7C8r9O0Td-vxshCeJjeeFjHD08_GDR3zzd_2Vr9hDdceZn6j2D6-jrQkn2pmTVXAp8XF3LxY-yiDeYwV8IekkPJkMgBI5IaB-olzD-g8PVflJ9_tBbejiQu8rJRCpIRhAs_5dqKU9SDl1Zbb5Z1Tg9z_8jIPVxmnLQhiT08hbIbGYZPir9egg93KJH9tQN2shhgfot6IoHxe_WeDuGDnt5tW8gYV0FtYdlP_LFc2MLPIW-AKnBbVRoif6ef3YwxGTKReBpHo4vHB0iI7I5NbbEapNBy7nabwd4dDnMArCVJj6Xc7aFP_S0qBuqNivUd1ErCqWs3f4itWf81FOdaAOPZUQMauJm--UpoyYcSy-O9u8LqEbKES2L2j11RZHLo7QFVuvLHxSDLMc0ppAIfAFrNvgoIT9eXSmCPrPHIC6CRGB0-poQxfGnQa65SGgvJDC8p9tvKJksFVWZw9uAyIKJfTxJNFArt3qvJENZF9ibiPLJy_iApl3w.GcWm0-PZzysRyQAOMHKQ79l8QFo2jcLAZSnBZTkWd2M&$select=members,securityEnabled,onPremisesSecurityIdentifier,mailNickname,displayName,id,onPremisesSyncEnabled,owners,groupTypes,mail,mailEnabled&$top=500
```

Answer (score 0):

I work for Microsoft Graph delta query team.

I have used the request id and times mentioned in the error message and  found the Microsoft Graph logs with  request id.

Error says : [API version mismatch: request version 25 with deltaLink version 27]

That means, Client has used the Delta link generated from the internal version 27 (AGSBetaB-internal) and made call to the internal version 25 (AGSv1-internal).

The problem I suspect here is **“Client has got the Delta Link by making call to MS Graph Beta version endpoint and then used that delta link to make a new call to MS Graph V1 version endpoint”.**

To confirm the above statement, we need the request id and time of the previous call which gave the delta link.

Please note : **Delta links are not sharable accross different API versions of Graph.**

Comment: I have cleared the connector and am trying again, will update when it completes and see the response I get this time.

Thank you for the quick reply

Comment: Well I have been unable to replicate this error since, due to the Full import now is no longer working.